# Label Display Integer

Tags: c#, combobox, label, alarm

I'm making a alarm clock in my application and the code requires me to set a variable int from a combo box into my program.

```
if ((e.Result.Text == "set a alarm") || (e.Result.Text == "set an alarm"))
        {
            Jarvis.Speak("setting alarm");
            label2.Content = DateTime.Today.Hour.ToString(HourAlarmCB) + ":" + DateTime.Today.Minute.ToString("54") + ":" + DateTime.Today.Second.ToString("00");
            label2.Opacity = 100;
            dispatcherTimer2.Start();
        }
```

The HourAlarmCB is the ComboBox with content in it "1","2", etc. but the error wont allow me to use ToString, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you may be incorrectly making use of `ToString()`.

Are you trying to retrieve the following formatted result?

```
hh:mm:ss
```

If so, you might find this approach worthy of consideration:

```cs
int hour = Convert.ToInt32(HourAlarmCB.SelectedItem);
int minute = DateTime.Today.Minute;
int second = DateTime.Today.Second;
label2.Content = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", hour, minute, second);
```

See [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for converting an arbitrary list of variables into a single formatted string.

For a description of `"D2"`, see [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DFormatString).

---

**Update:** First, note that [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns "an object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00."

Now, in reference to your question, to output `AM` or `PM`, use the [`t` standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```cs
DateTime date = DateTime.Today; // time is '00:00:00'
int hour = Convert.ToInt32(HourAlarmCB.SelectedItem);
int minute = date.Minute; // always '0'
int second = date.Second; // always '0'

label2.Content = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2} {3:t}",
    hour, minute, second, date); // for example: '08:00:00 AM'
```

Comment: Umm I did something like that, that was my old code and since then I have change lots of it. But do you know why a Time of Day "tt" would return "P2" instead of "PM"?

Answer (score 0):

So the end result is me having to the HourAlarmCB variable to a string

```
if ((e.Result.Text == "set a alarm") || (e.Result.Text == "set an alarm"))
        {
            Jarvis.Speak("setting alarm");
            string HourAlarmStr = HourAlarmCB.SelectedItem.ToString();
            label2.Content = DateTime.Today.Hour.ToString(HourAlarmStr) + ":" + DateTime.Today.Minute.ToString("54") + ":" + DateTime.Today.Second.ToString("00");
            label2.Opacity = 100;
            dispatcherTimer2.Start();
        }
```